# Selenium 3.0.1 and Firefox 50.0 in headless mode launches browser on visible screen

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ubuntu-14.04, selenium3

I have successfully used non gecko version of Firefox driver in headless mode but it has stopped working since I started using Selenium 3.0. What I do -

- Start xvfb
- Set `webdriver.gecko.driver` to path to gecko driver
- Set Firefox binary display

```html
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path to geckodriver");                    
String Xport = System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id", ":1"); final 
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(); 
firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null); 
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

But this launches the browser on visible screen and not on headless mode. What else do I need to to do to launch Firefox on xvfb?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the xPort display value is set to :10 instead of :1

If it's not, just try setting it to **:10** and recheck:

```
 firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":10");
```

Comment: It is set to 1 and not 10